a sequence of points being in general position
Let $X$ be a countable (finite or denumerable) subset of $E^n$ (Euclidean space). Each point is, trivially, a linear subspace of $E^n$, and the set $X$ generates a countable sublattice, $L(X)$ say, of the lattice of all linear subspace of $E^n$. Let $\Omega(X)$ be the set union of all proper linear subspaces in $L(X)$. Since $L(X)$ is countable, the complement $E^n - \Omega(X)$ is everywhere dense. Define $y \in E^n$ to be in general position with respect to $X$ if $y \notin \Omega(X)$.
Now let $\Delta$ be an $n$-simplex and $X$ a finite set of points in $\Delta$. We say $y \in \Delta$ is in general position with respect to X if the same is true for some linear embedding $\Delta \subset E^n$.
Let $\Delta'$ be a subdivision of $\Delta$, with vertices $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r$ say. We define an ordered sequence $(y_1,\dots,y_s) \subset \Delta$ to be in general position with respect to $\Delta'$ if, for each $i$, $1 \leq i \leq s$, $y_i$ is in general position with respect to the set $(x_1,\dots,x_r,y_1,\dots,y_{i-1})$.
These definitions related to points being in general position are given in Chapter 6 General Position, E.C. Zeeman's Seminar on Combinatorial Topology (available here)
Zeeman points out that for a sequence of points in general position by this definition, if the order is changed they may no longer be so. A counter-example is given as follows: in $E^2$, choose 4 points $X$ such that $\Omega(X)$ contains all rationals on the real axis (regarding $E^2$ as the complex numbers), and then add $\pi$, $\sqrt{\pi}$ in that order. (As pointed out by Kohan in the comments, Zeeman is also looking at rational spans.)
I had trouble understanding this example. First, how do we select the four points that meet the requirement? Second, why does the sequence lose its general position if we change the order?

The expression "the set union of all proper linear subspace" does not parse even on the syntax level.

@moisheKohan now I use the exact language from Zeeman. Wish it'd be clear.

I looked at the book (available here). One critical part that you omitted is that they also look at rational linear combinations and rational affine spans (incorrectly called "linear"). This is what the counter-example refers to (it makes no sense if one uses real spans).
